# Branch does not exist

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, setup-deployment, continuous-deployment

the command

```
git branch --set-upstream-to develop origin/develop
```

results in the error

```
fatal: branch 'origin/develop' does not exist
```

I am not sure what this means other than origin develop does not exist. Does that mean it doesn't exist on the server or on my local machine?

I am a git newbie but I am in the process of setting up my site to handle deployments with git as a means to learn git.

Comment: Well, what branches _do_ exist?  `git branch -avvv`

Answer (score 6):

`origin` is the name of a remote, which is just another repo that your repo knows about. You name repos when adding them, ala `git remote add somename other/repo/path`, and then you can `fetch` and `pull` from them, and if they're bare repos, `push` to them. When you clone a repo, git sets up a remote for you pointing to the one you cloned from, and names it `origin` by default. `origin/develop` refers to the `develop` branch in the `origin` remote repo.

If you've made a branch locally, you can push it to a particular remote to create it there, and until you've created it there, you can't set it as upstream. In your case, you would do `git push origin develop`. Then you could set it as upstream, but you can squeeze that operation into the push operation with `-u`, so `git push -u origin develop`, which both pushes your branch to `origin`, and sets up your local branch to track it. Note that `push -u` was added in git 1.7.0.

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you are at `develop` branch.
Then just use `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop`

Answer (score 1):

Git defines `git branch --set-upstream-to <upstream> [<branchname>]`.

Here `<upstream>` specifies the remote branch and `[<branchname>]` is the local branch name and if you no branch is specified, it defaults to the current branch.

So, it should be `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop develop`

`-u` is interchangeable with `--set-upstream-to`

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

You may need to run `git fetch <upstream>` before running `git branch --set-upstream-to <upstream>`.

---

Today I ran into a similar issue while working on a public repo on Github. I cloned the public repo, made changes locally, then realised that I forgot to first fork this repo on GitHub. So I went ahead and forked it now, but I could not set the local branch to track my fork:

```bash
# conventionally it's named 'upstream', but it coincides with git terminology
# so for clarity's sake, I'll name it 'source' in this example
git remote rename origin source
git remote add origin <my-fork>

# errors here:
# fatal: the requested upstream branch 'origin' does not exist
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

Basically what's happening is that your local repo isn't aware of the branches in `origin`, and indeed git hints that you may wish to run `git fetch` first. However a simple `git fetch` won't do it, since it automatically fetches from the current default remote, which is still `source`.

So what you actually need to do first is either:

```bash
# one time
git fetch origin
```

or

```bash
# also set origin as default remote for fetch
git fetch --set-upstream origin
```

Then your `git branch --set-upstream-to ...` should work as expected.